# How to Sync the particular document from couchbase server?

Tags: swift, couchdb, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am developing an application. In that application I had used the couchbase Lite for mobile. I did with syncing of all documents in the database from couchbase server. but the problem is that the database is large. I dont want to sync all documents from couchbase server. I want to sync only particular data/document from server.

My question is, how can I sync a particular document related to that particular user?

Comment: This is what [channels](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/sync-gateway/channels/index.html) are for.

Comment: Also you tagged the question couchdb but named the question Couchbase Server.  Which are you using?

Comment: @borrrden Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 3):

Document access for a particular user is done in the Sync Function. It's a function written in JavaScript that resides in the configuration file of Sync Gateway.

The methods available in the Sync Function are:

- `channel(channelname)`: Route a document to a channel.
- `access(username, channelname)`: Grant a username access to a channel (possibility to grant a role to a channel too, and as a result all users with that role get access to the channel).
- `role(username, rolename)`: Assign a user with a role.
- `requireAccess(channelname)`: Throws an error if the user in the context doesn't already have access to the channel.
- `requireUser(username)`: Throws an error if the user in the context isn't the username.
- `requireRole(rolename)`: Throws and error if the the user in the context doesn't have the role rolename.
- `throw({forbidden: "error message"})`: Throw an exception for custom validation.

Here's an example of a config file with inline comments:

```
{
  "log": ["REST", "CRUD"],
  "users": {
    "foo1": {"password": "letmein", "admin_roles": ["admin"]},
    "foo2": {"password": "letmein"}
  },
  "databases": {
    "quizz": {
      "sync": `function(doc, oldDoc) {
        // The owner field shouldn't change during updates
        if (doc.owner != oldDoc.owner) {
          throw({forbidden: "Can't change the owner field on existing documents"});
        }
        switch(doc.type) {
          case "list":
            // only users with admin role can create/update list documents
            requireRole("admin");
            break;
          case "todo":
           // only the owner of a todo document can create/update it
           require(doc.owner);
           break;
        }
      }`
    }
  }
}
```

Note: The Sync Function should be pure which means that given an input (a document revision), the output should remain the same regardless of time (i.e. you can't make database/http requests for example). Also, it's not possible to modify the revision in the sync function.

See the [docs](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/sync-gateway/sync-function-api-guide/index.html) on the Sync Function for more detail and [this tutorial](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mini-hacks/tree/master/channels-users-roles) for a more in-depth example.